# Save a variable before throw exception() or addGlobalError()

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, throw, validationerror

Good day,

In a java web application, I have a button for user to click and I will do some logic in the method. And I am planing to do a checking, which is `doSomething()` if user click more than 5 times on this button and (hit some logic and throw exception). Thus, I create a variable to store the number of clicks. My code as follow:

```
@Session
private int count; 

    public Resolution add() throws BaseException {

      if ( count >= 5 ) {
        doSomething();
      }

      if ( true ) {
        count++;
        throw BaseValidationException();
      }

      return view( );
    }
```

However, the `count++` will not +1 to count after `throw BaseValidationException()`. 
But if I remove the `throw BaseValidationException()`, then the system will run to `doSomething()` after I click 5 times on the `add` button.

I believe that throw Exception() or `addGlobalError()` will not store the variable value into session. Any ideas to overcome this other than store the value to db?

Comment: Why you are not adding counter value to the session or cookies , session.setCounter("counter",counter);

Comment: In servlet (In java Web App) it is not recommend to create instance variable  in Servlet, specially to store the user data.

Comment: The count is not consider user data right? user cant edit on it through UI, user does not know this variable exists also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
private int count; 

    public Resolution add() throws BaseException {
       HttpSession session=request.getSession();
       int count=(Integer)session.getAttribute("count");
      if ( count >= 5 ) {
        doSomething();
      }

      if ( true ) {
        count++;

        session.setAttribute("count",count);
        throw BaseValidationException();
      }

      return view( );
    }
```

Comment: Can you remove "private int count;" or is that required?

Comment: No it is not required.